# Почему не экранируются кавычки в термиинале? (Perl, Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, perl, text

Исходная задача - отредактировать файл из терминала. Вставляю в него строку следующим образом:

```
perl -pi -lwe 'print qq{["\$jk_lib/\$LibFile","\$jk_lib/../../htslib/libhts.a",'-lz', '-lssl']}  if $. == 3' Build.PL
```

строка вставляется, но теряются одинарные кавычки. При попытке их экранировать - терминал ожидает дальнейшего ввода.

```
perl -pi -lwe 'print qq{["\$jk_lib/\$LibFile","\$jk_lib/../../htslib/libhts.a",\'-lz\', \'-lssl\']}  if $. == 3' Build.PL
>
```

Пробовала сделать sed'ом - история та же.

Почему кавычки не экранируются и как можно вставить эту строку средствами командной строки?

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to escape quotes in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30903/1321)

Comment: @jfs, там скорее всего надо _\\\\_ (без подчёркивания) для экранирования использовать.

Comment: @0andriy: о чём вы? где там? и почему "надо"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Экранирование кавычек в баше часто сплошная боль. В многих случаях нужно вместо одной одинарной кавычки писать где то так `'"'"'` ([объяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)).

В Вашем случае легче там просто двойные кавычки написать. 
Или воспользоваться функцией q.

```
'-lz', '-lssl'
```

превратится в

```
q(-lz), q(-lssl)
```